# Boost Library to find parent's process ID

Tags: c++, linux, windows, boost, process

I am really messed up with the code base I have and I am working on portability of C++ code.

As of now the code seems to be windows specific and it tries to take the parent's process ID that is executing itself. Eg: I write a code in C++ that uses the Parent's process ID of the cmd that is executing the corresponding EXE created by its (code's)compilation.

```
DWORD getParentPID()
{
  HANDLE hSnapshot;
  PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
  DWORD parentPID = 0, PID = GetCurrentProcessId();
  hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );
  __try{
      if( hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) __leave;
      ZeroMemory( &pe32, sizeof( pe32 ) );
      pe32.dwSize = sizeof( pe32 );
      if( !Process32First( hSnapshot, &pe32 ) ) __leave;
      do{
        if( pe32.th32ProcessID == PID ){
            parentPID = pe32.th32ParentProcessID;
            break;
         }
      }while( Process32Next( hSnapshot, &pe32 ) );
   }
   __finally{
     if( hSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) CloseHandle( hSnapshot );
   }
  return parentPID;
}
```

Obviously, this code is not intended to work on Linux and I don't want any precompilation, Looking forward to some platform independent code using Boost C++.

PS: Precompilation up to som extent is accepted. Mainly Targeted platforms are Windows and Linux.I might be missing on some small points due to the workload.

Any Lead is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: *Why* don't you want to use [conditional compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_compilation)? Especially since on Linux (as well as on macOS and other POSIX compatible systems) it is a [single system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getppid.2.html) to get the parent pid.

Comment: Oh Cool @Someprogrammerdude I'm Certainly using this and conditional compilation (Y)